Handling button clicks with android and Visual Studio
I am new in Android Programming. I am developing an Android App Project and wanna to handle a function using a button.click in XML. This is my snipped of code, which seems to be good, but don't work
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="kliked" />

and the C# code:
namespace PrzyciskTestOfficial
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        }
        public void kliked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Button).Text = "Click me again!";
        }
    }
}

As I understand correctly, it is enough, I have no idea why program is closing after clicking a button.
